# Convert and switch between element on LinkedList

Tags: java

i want to convert the element in object (item2) to contain "*" based on the size of the object (item) elements
        e.g

```
    item2.get(0) should produce the output of "****" instead of "book"


public void convert(){

    LinkedList<String> item = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<String> item2 = new LinkedList<String>();

    item.add("book");
    item.add("pen");
    item.add("chair");
    item2 = item;

    System.out.println(item2.get(0));


}
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Have you tried playing around with a for loop based on the size of the String object?

Comment: I have tried to convert the element in item2 by trying to create seperate String array and autobox it, so this array would contain "*" then i can add it to the item2 collection.   But i want each element size be according to the object item size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple regex if you just want to replace all characters in your string with `*` character:

```
System.out.println(item2.get(0).replaceAll(".", "*"));
```

Comment: Note that this replaces every char including spaces and new line.

Comment: Thanks so much... I think i need to go fill my head with regex

Answer (score 0):

With java 11, you can use the new method [String.repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)):

```
System.out.println("*".repeat(item2.get(0).length()));
```

Comment: What about other version like 7,8 that are widely used

Comment: A simple for loop with a StringBuilder would do the job.